# Jquery multiple selector filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working example of code I need, but some improvement is required.

```js
$("#filtroSolicitacoes").on("submit", function(){
    
    $("#solicitacoes div").show();
    
    var filter = "";
    
    $(this).find("[data-form]").each(function(){
    
        if( $(this).val() != "" ) filter += ("[" + $(this).attr("data-form") + "='" + $(this).val() + "']");
    
    });
    
    if(filter.length > 0) $("#solicitacoes div").not(filter).hide();

    return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filtros">
    <form id="filtroSolicitacoes" type="post" name="filtroSolicitacoes">
        Protocolo: <input data-form="id" type="text" name="filtroProtocolo" id="filtroProtocolo" size="5"/>
        Solicitante: <input data-form="title" type="text" name="filtroSolicitante" id="filtroSolicitante" size="10"/>
        Status: 
        <select data-form="status" name="filtroStatus" id="filtroStatus">
        <option value="">-- Selecione Status--</option>
        <option value="3">Aguardando Aprova&ccedil;&atilde;o</option>
        <option value="18">Encaminhado</option>
        <option value="2">Iniciado</option>
        <option value="1">N&atilde;o Iniciado</option>
        <option value="4">Pendente de Esclarecimento</option>
        <option value="16">Reiniciado</option>
        <option value="6">Reprovado</option>
        </select>
        Analista: 
        <select data-form="analista" name="filtroAnalista" id="filtroAnalista">
            <option value="">-- Selecione Analista--</option>
            <option value="23">Robert</option>
            <option value="46">Allan</option>
            <option value="49">Edward</option>
            <option value="32">Jake</option>
            <option value="14">Stella</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" id="filtrar" style="float:right; margin-right:10px">:: Filtrar ::</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="solicitacoes">
    <div id='1' title='Mike' status='18' analista='23'>Whatever content 1</div>
    <div id='2' title='John' status='16' analista='46'>Whatever content 2</div>
    <div id='3' title='Tom' status='2' analista='49'>Whatever content 3</div>
    <div id='4' title='Mike' status='4' analista='23'>Whatever content 4</div>
    <div id='5' title='Kate' status='3' analista='32'>Whatever content 5</div>
    <div id='6' title='Steve' status='1' analista='14'>Whatever content 6</div>
</div>
```

Filterable items have single property:

```
<div id='6' title='Steve' status='1' analista='14'>Whatever content 6</div>
```

here status='1' attribute can have only one value (1 in this case). I need to be able add multiple values in one attribute, like so:

```
<div id='6' title='Steve' status='1 2' analista='14 15'>Whatever content 6</div>
```

And items with corresponding values must be shown up after filtration.

Unfortunately my knowledge doesn't admit me made that improvement, your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Custom attributes aren't necessarily the way to go. Since you're already using jQuery, perhaps [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) would be helpful.

Comment: Do you need data in array form for server-side?

Comment: Quick note, never use selectors like `$("#solicitacoes div")`.  JQuery reads right to left so that literally finds every `div` and checks to see if it is inside `#solicitacoes`.  Instead use `$("#solicitacoes").find("div")` because that finds the `#solicitacoes` first and then checks inside it for any `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem lies in how you are constructing your filter:

```
if( $(this).val() != "" )
    filter += ("[" + $(this).attr("data-form") + "='" + $(this).val() + "']");
```

This means that you can only select a attribute that **exacty matches** the value, so if you have space separated values in your attributes, e.g. `analista='14 15'`, the filter `[analista='14']` or `[analista='15']` will never match. Of course, one may find the easy way out of using the `*=` comparator, but that is very unreliable because that means `[analista*='14']` will match any elements that contain `analista="14 15"` and also `analista="140000"` for example.

The fix I am proposing is going to slightly rewrite your filtering logic, so do stick with me step-by-step:

1. Remember to use `data-` attributes for non-standard attributes, i.e. you can keep `id` and `title`, but use `data-status` and `data-analista` instead of `status` and `analista` respectively.
2. In your JS, we can cache the `$("#solicitacoes").find("div")` collection for performance.
3. Instead of creating a concatenated string of `filter`, we simply create an empty object. It will serve as a dictionary with contains the attribute stored as the key, and the input field values as the values.
4. When that dictionary is created, we use the `for (var x in ...)` syntax to iterate through all keys in your dictionary.

   - In each iteration, we will have access to the attribute that we want to filter and the value we are interested in. That is your *entry* of the dictionary.
   - With this in hand, you can iterate through the cached collection of `$("#solicitacoes").find("div")`. We want to access the value of the attribute of interest, and then split/explode the string by the space character, so `data-analista="14 15"` for example will be converted into an array of `[14, 15]`.
   - Check if the array contains the value in the dictionary entry

See proof-of-concept below: I have added additional space-separated values to the first `<div>` to illustrate the example.

```js
$("#filtroSolicitacoes").on("submit", function() {
  // Cache collection
  var $divsToFilter = $("#solicitacoes").find("div");
  
  $divsToFilter.show();

  var dictionary = {};

  $(this).find("[data-form]").each(function() {
    if (this.value)
      dictionary[$(this).attr('data-form')] = this.value;
  });

  // Loop through the dictionary to access individual entries
  for (var key in dictionary) {
  
    // We have the key, use it to get the value
    var value = dictionary[key];
    
    // Filter the divs
    $divsToFilter.filter(function() {
    
      // Explode/split all space-separate values stored in attribute into an array
      var dataValues = $(this).attr(key);
      
      // Check if our dictioanry entry's value matches any in the array
      // If it is missing, we want to keep it in the filter so that we can hide it
      return dataValues.indexOf(value) === -1;
      
    }).hide();
  }

  return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filtros">
  <form id="filtroSolicitacoes" type="post" name="filtroSolicitacoes">
    Protocolo: <input data-form="id" type="text" name="filtroProtocolo" id="filtroProtocolo" size="5" /> Solicitante: <input data-form="title" type="text" name="filtroSolicitante" id="filtroSolicitante" size="10" /> Status:
    <select data-form="data-status" name="filtroStatus" id="filtroStatus">
      <option value="">-- Selecione Status--</option>
      <option value="3">Aguardando Aprova&ccedil;&atilde;o</option>
      <option value="18">Encaminhado</option>
      <option value="2">Iniciado</option>
      <option value="1">N&atilde;o Iniciado</option>
      <option value="4">Pendente de Esclarecimento</option>
      <option value="16">Reiniciado</option>
      <option value="6">Reprovado</option>
    </select>
    Analista:
    <select data-form="data-analista" name="filtroAnalista" id="filtroAnalista">
      <option value="">-- Selecione Analista--</option>
      <option value="23">Robert</option>
      <option value="46">Allan</option>
      <option value="49">Edward</option>
      <option value="32">Jake</option>
      <option value="14">Stella</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id="filtrar" style="float:right; margin-right:10px">:: Filtrar ::</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="solicitacoes">
  <div id='1' title='Mike' data-status='18 16 2' data-analista='23 46 49'>Whatever content 1</div>
  <div id='2' title='John' data-status='16' data-analista='46'>Whatever content 2</div>
  <div id='3' title='Tom' data-status='2' data-analista='49'>Whatever content 3</div>
  <div id='4' title='Mike' data-status='4' data-analista='23'>Whatever content 4</div>
  <div id='5' title='Kate' data-status='3' data-analista='32'>Whatever content 5</div>
  <div id='6' title='Steve' data-status='1' data-analista='14'>Whatever content 6</div>
</div>
```

---

**Bonus if you're using ES6**: everything can be made slightly simpler. This is when you realise you don't actually need jQuery all the time ;)

```js
document.getElementById('filtroSolicitacoes').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const divsToFilter = document.querySelectorAll('#solicitacoes div');
  const userFilters = e.target.querySelectorAll('[data-form]');
  
  Array.from(divsToFilter).forEach(element => element.style.display = 'block');
  
  const dictionary = {};
 
  Array.from(userFilters).forEach(input => {
    if (input.value)
      dictionary[input.dataset.form] = input.value;
  });
  
  for (let key in dictionary) {
    const value = dictionary[key];
    
    Array.from(divsToFilter).forEach(element => {
      var dataValues = element.getAttribute(key);
      
      if (!dataValues.includes(value))
        element.style.display = 'none';
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="filtros">
  <form id="filtroSolicitacoes" type="post" name="filtroSolicitacoes">
    Protocolo: <input data-form="id" type="text" name="filtroProtocolo" id="filtroProtocolo" size="5" /> Solicitante: <input data-form="title" type="text" name="filtroSolicitante" id="filtroSolicitante" size="10" /> Status:
    <select data-form="data-status" name="filtroStatus" id="filtroStatus">
      <option value="">-- Selecione Status--</option>
      <option value="3">Aguardando Aprova&ccedil;&atilde;o</option>
      <option value="18">Encaminhado</option>
      <option value="2">Iniciado</option>
      <option value="1">N&atilde;o Iniciado</option>
      <option value="4">Pendente de Esclarecimento</option>
      <option value="16">Reiniciado</option>
      <option value="6">Reprovado</option>
    </select>
    Analista:
    <select data-form="data-analista" name="filtroAnalista" id="filtroAnalista">
      <option value="">-- Selecione Analista--</option>
      <option value="23">Robert</option>
      <option value="46">Allan</option>
      <option value="49">Edward</option>
      <option value="32">Jake</option>
      <option value="14">Stella</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id="filtrar" style="float:right; margin-right:10px">:: Filtrar ::</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="solicitacoes">
  <div id='1' title='Mike' data-status='18 16 2' data-analista='23 46 49'>Whatever content 1</div>
  <div id='2' title='John' data-status='16' data-analista='46'>Whatever content 2</div>
  <div id='3' title='Tom' data-status='2' data-analista='49'>Whatever content 3</div>
  <div id='4' title='Mike' data-status='4' data-analista='23'>Whatever content 4</div>
  <div id='5' title='Kate' data-status='3' data-analista='32'>Whatever content 5</div>
  <div id='6' title='Steve' data-status='1' data-analista='14'>Whatever content 6</div>
</div>
```